# How do I access array elements if the dimension can vary?

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing

I have data stored in an array as for example

```
myList = array([('A', 3, 2, 5),('B', 3, 7, 0),dtype=[('f0', '<U128'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])
```

It has a constant number of columns >2 and an arbitrary number of rows.
I would like to read the 2nd column into a new array. I know I can do this with

```
[x[1] for x in myList]
```

or

```
list(zip(*myList))[1]
```

But the problem in my case is, that in some cases the array has only one line, then I only want the value `myList[1]` and the above code. I could use an if-condition for this, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to treat the array, when the dimension can vary?

Comment: there is always the same number of columns, so this only happens when there is 0 rows, which is not a problem. The problem is, when there is 1 row, because then the array has only 1 index

Comment: When there is only one row, I want the second entry of the list, so myList[1]

Comment: `myList` is of type `np.ndarray`? Or is it an actual `list` type?

Comment: What do you mean by nested lists?  `genfromtxt` does not return a list.  It will either return a 2d array or a 1d array with a compound `dtype`.  What's the arrays `shape` and `dtype`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was unprecise about the types. So, `mylist` is of type `np.ndarray` and in case there is more than 1 line, `mylist[0]` is of type `np.void`. Which means, i could do it by `[[x[1] for x in mylist] if isinstance(mylist[1], np.void) else mylist[1]]`

Comment: `np.ndarray` already have indexing supported.  You don't need list comprehension to accomplish that.  See my answer.

Comment: yes, thanks for the answer. Just `mylist[:,1]` does not work in my case, maybe since there are strings in the array. Maybe I should use a different command than `genfromtxt`?

Comment: It would be a good idea to share some sample input and expected output then.  Please see how to create a [mre].  Even if there are strings it shouldn't matter - as long as there is a second element in each sub-array then it should still work. I'm guessing you don't have a uniform shape?

Comment: ok, I will try to rephrase the question. But I suppose there is no way to do it without an if-condition. I am just a bit puzzled about the fact that the array changes the way it wants to be treated if it has a dimension less..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to recreate the problem. I have made a txt file containing:

```
'A', 3, 2, 5
'B', 3, 7, 0
```

Loading this file with numpys `genfromtext` leads to your array. The following code extracts the first column regardless of the number of rows:

```
import numpy as np

myList = np.genfromtxt("startFile.txt", dtype="U128,f8,f8", delimiter=",")
numRows = np.shape([myList])[0]
reshapedList = np.reshape(myList, (numRows, -1))
columnValues = [x[1] for x in reshapedList[0]]
print(f"column values: {columnValues}")
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Provided `myList` is an actual `numpy` array,

```
def func(arr):
    if len(arr.shape) == 1:
        return arr[1]
    else:
        return arr[:, 1]

result = func(myList)
```

If `myList` is a type `list` instead:

```
def func(lst):
    if isinstance(lst[0], list):
        return [x[1] for x in lst]
    else:
        return lst[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work?

```
myList = [[1],[1,2,3],[1,2]]
[*map(lambda x: x[1] if len(x)>1 else None,  myList)]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my case is different. The sub-lists have all the same lengths, but the length of myList can vary